# Facebook Share Button is ignoring og:meta tags

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-sharer

I have tried using the direct link to sharer.php but with the problems managing the popup window and closing it, and the fact that Facebook gives no documentation on it with the real parameters (ie p[title], etc.), it seems imprudent to rely on that method.

So I am following the instructions given by Facebook, and it doesn't pick up any of the meta properties they have defined. I have copied the syntax directly, it is placed properly in the head of the HTML document, and that entire HTML document is in an iFrame to prevent any outside interaction.  The Share window pops up as expected, but none of the properties (save the url included in the a tag) are populated.

Ironically, when I navigate directly to that page in my browser, and instead, click on the Share on Facebook bookmarklet, it DOES correctly read the meta properties!

Any suggestions would be appreciated, unless they are, "use the like button", because it's not at all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook ignores your meta tags when they are used in an iframe and inserts it's own. This is by design. I think it is possible to use a 'sharer' link though...

Comment: Damn! And that was the only way I could accomplish multiple share buttons on the same page, with different information. Guess I'll have to hack the bookmarklet and hope they don't change it. They really would have a hard time making it more inconvenient to allow third parties to share content on their user's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook fetch title, description and image from og properties. Check u r properly added open graph meta tags for shared url. Then test that url using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug